# Show only image files In input type file browse window?

Tags: php, jquery, html

so basically how to filter the window popup to only show images files when i click the input type file

```
 <input type="file" />
```

any help appreciated, I try to find a solution for this

Thanks

Comment: Errr Qué? I don't follow, can you provide more detail, whats the popup, etc.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861699/how-do-you-get-a-html-browse-button-to-filter-and-show-only-images

Comment: This is not possible to control with the default file browser. The attribute `accept="image/*"` may be of use to the file types accepted but as far as only displaying specific files types is concerned I believe a javascript solution is the only way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this, but it won't work in all browsers:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

In Chrome you could even specify the formats you allow:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

[LIVING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/FkJpc/)

If you want to restrict the image type [you can still use JavaScript to validate it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382514/1081396) on the client side.

But of course you should check it on the server side with PHP as well:

```
//defining the allowed extensions and types for our system.
$allowedMimes = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/wbmp');
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'wbmp');

$extension = end(explode('.',$imgFile));

//is the extension allowed?
if(in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)){

    //getting the mime type (it can be different from the extension) Be careful!
    $imgInfo = getimagesize('yourPath/'.$imgFile);
    $type = strtolower($imgInfo['mime']);

    //checking the mime type
    if(!in_array($type, $allowedMimes)){
         // is an allowed image type
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test your own demo? what browsers did you find it worked in?

Comment: @Dagon I only tested it on Chrome. You are right. It doesn't work over others.

Comment: i found it worked on IE, but not FF

Comment: @Dagon, anyway, the `image/*` doesn't work on all browsers either. Is more about validation.

Comment: extensions are meaningless and ereg_replace is depreciated.

Comment: @Dagon changed for `explode` + `end`.

Answer (score 8):

I think u are looking for the accept parameter. Try this works

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

For the list of mime types, check the link below:

http://www.bitsandpix.com/entry/microsoft-office-2007-2010-docx-xlsx-pptx-mime-type-to-avoid-the-zip-issue/

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. That's part of Browser's user interface  and JavaScript has no control on it. As other mention you can use `accept` attribute but that attribute  hasn't been created for this purpose.

> If the value of the `type` attribute is `file`, `accept` attribute indicates the types of files that the server accepts; otherwise it is ignored. The value must be a comma-separated list of unique content type specifier.

Answer (score 1):

Image for example:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful)